# Setting scale range for MapImageLayer in ArcGIS JavaScript API

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am trying to set scale range in JS API v 4.x as [seen here in 3.x](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/121798/how-to-set-scale-range-for-a-graphic-layer-in-arcgis-api/121863).  However when I try to use the load event as in the example it does not work in 4.x.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this same task in 4.x?

This is how its accomplished in 3.x but this is not working in 4.x (setting scale range for MapImageLayer in 4.x):

```
    map.on("load", mapLoaded);
  
    function mapLoaded(){

      // Set min/max scales for the map's graphics layer.
      map.graphics.setMinScale(10000000);
      map.graphics.setMaxScale(9000000);
      // Could also use setScaleRange.
      // map.graphics.setScaleRange(10000000, 9000000);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The 4.x API doesn't use "set" methods to change properties. Instead, you change the property itself. See this page for information about [Setters](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/programming-patterns/#setters). You can set the GraphicsLayer class properties [maxScale](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-GraphicsLayer.html#maxScale) and [minScale](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-GraphicsLayer.html#minScale) directly.

Additionally, Map doesn't have any event listeners in 4.x. Instead, that is handled by the [MapView](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/migrating/#views).

Comment: kenbuja thank you for your contribution!  I was able to resolve the issue as seen in my answer.  I ended up using extent and having arcgis take care of the scale automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue by actually using the Extent property in JS 4.x.  Since the scale is derived from the extent, you can set the extent to set your scale.  Then you don't have to set the scale.  So if you have the extent, you can use that as follows in 4.x:

```
// new extent for the mapview where the spatialReference.wkid is 4326
const initialExtent= new Extent({
  xmin: -9177882,
  ymin: 4246761,
  xmax: -9176720,
  ymax: 4247967,
  spatialReference: {
    wkid: 102100
  }
});

const view = new MapView({
  map: map,
  container: "viewDiv",
  zoom: 10,
  extent: initialExtent, // will override zoom
  // map will be centered at [0,0], but the scale from initialExtent will be used
  center: [0,0]
});
```

Here is the reference:

[JavaScript API Reference - Extent](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-views-MapView.html#extent)